# Javadoc for Apache Camel not found in Spring Tool Suite (Eclipse)

Tags: eclipse, spring, maven, apache-camel, javadoc

My Spring Tool Suite does not find the Javadoc (or the sources) for Apache Camel. E.g. when hovering over Exchange.getIn(), the following message is shown:

> Note: This element neither has attached source nor attached Javadoc
>   and hence no Javadoc could be found.

How can I append the Javadoc? Is there any other way than including the camel sources as a dependency in Maven?

I'm using STS 3.7.2, based on Eclipse Mars 4.5.1 with camel 2.8.3 as a dependency in Maven.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using eclipse with maven you can set your configurations to automatically download the source code and JavaDocs for your libraries.

```
Window -> Preferenes -> Maven
-Select Download Artifact Sources
-Select Download Artifact JavaDoc
```